# Reproducing R's gaussian process maximum likelihood regression in Python

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, gaussian

I have implemented a function in R to estimate the Gaussian Process parameters of a basic sin function. Unfortunately the project has to be made in Python and I have been trying to reproduce the behavior of R library's hetGP in python using SKlearn but I have a hard time mapping the former to the later.

My understanding of Gaussian Processes is still limited and I am a beginner with sklearn, so I would really appreciate some help on this one.

My R code:

```
library(hetGP)

set.seed(123)
nvar <- 2
n <- 400
r <- 1
f <- function(x) sin(sum(x))
true_C <- matrix(1/8 * (3 + 2 * cos(2) - cos(4)), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)

design <- matrix(runif(nvar*n), ncol = nvar)
response <- apply(design, 1, f)
model <- mleHomGP(design, response, lower = rep(1e-4, nvar), upper = rep(1,nvar))
```

Later in the code, I use `model$Ki` and `model$theta`

```
model$theta: 0.9396363 0.9669170
dim(model$ki): 400 400
```

My Python code so far:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF

n = 400
n_var = 2
real_c = np.full((2, 2), 1 / 8 * (3 + 2 * np.cos(2) - np.cos(4)))
design = np.random.uniform(size=n * n_var).reshape(-1, 2)
test = np.random.uniform(size=n * n_var).reshape(-1, 2)
response = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.sin(np.sum(x)), 1, design)
kernel = RBF(length_scale=(1, 1))
gpr = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, n_restarts_optimizer=10,
                               optimizer="fmin_l_bfgs_b").fit(design, response)
gpr.predict(test, return_std=True)
theta = gpr.kernel_.get_params()["length_scale"]
#theta = gpr.kernel_.theta
k_inv = gpr._K_inv
```

`theta = [1.78106558 1.80083585]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## After more than a week, I finally found an answer.

### (By looking at `Scikit-learn` and `hetGP` implementations)

There are many different points in their implementations.

- First, the noise level as well as sigma have to be explicitly instantiated in sklearn or they won't be optimized.
- Furthermore, the best way to find k_inv is to use GaussianProcessRegressor.L_, the lower part of the Cholesky decomposition of K.
- Finally `hetGP` doesn't scale their K by `sigma`, so we have to do it manualy.

### How I did:

```
import scipy
import numpy as np
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import ConstantKernel, RBF, WhiteKernel


n = 400
n_var = 2

design = np.random.uniform(size=n * n_var).reshape((-1, n_var))
response = np.array([np.sin(np.sum(row)) for row in design])

real_c = np.full((n_var, n_var), 1 / 8 * (3 + 2 * np.cos(2) - np.cos(4)))

# Kernel has to have a constant kernel for sigma, a n_var dimension length_scale and a white kernel to optimize the noise
kernel = ConstantKernel(1e-8) * RBF(length_scale=np.array([1.0, 1.0])) + WhiteKernel(noise_level=1)

gpr = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, alpha=1e-10)    
gpr.fit(design, response)

L_inv = scipy.linalg.solve_triangular(gpr.L_.T, np.eye(gpr.L_.shape[0]))
k_inv = L_inv.dot(L_inv.T)
sigma_f = gpr.kernel_.k1.get_params()['k1__constant_value']

theta = gpr.kernel_.k1.get_params()['k2__length_scale']

Ki = k_inv * sigma_f
```